# Domain and Repository cross references in Ninject

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject

I have 3 projects:`Contracts`, `Domain`, `Repository`.

`Contracts` have interfaces. 
`Domain` and `Repository` both reference `Contracts`.

The constructor of the `Domain` class gets passed `IRepo`. 
The constructor of the `Repository` class gets passed `IDomain`.

The WebAPI throws default constructor is not set. 
If I remove the constructor for the `Repository` then everything works fine. 
Both classes have a default parameterless constructor.

The problem is that the `Repository` needs to return a concrete object of type `Domain`, but can't do so because it doesn't have a reference to `Domain`.

Comment: If `Repository` needs to return types that are in `Domain` then I imagine it should reference `Domain`, shouldn't it?  That wouldn't create a circular reference in your setup.

Comment: I have a setup of UI, Service, Domain(model+logic), Persistence, and Contracts. U communicates with S through HTTP(S), and S, D, P all reference C. I think I'll have the P's constructor be parameter-less and have all the P methods have a ref parameter of the interface for D. That way I can pass in the domain objects to the P and have it get filled. I'll try that and if it works I'll post an answer.

Comment: Show us some code so that we can help better. Why are domain object injected into repos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to remove the constructor parameters and pass in an entity to the any methods that need it.